# How to generate Django models from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a csv file with 3300+ lines which discribes the database structure. I'm using pandas.read_csv() for parsing.
Here is a small example of my file (the first line is headers):

```
"Variable / Field Name","Form Name","Section Header","Field Type","Field Label","Choices, Calculations, OR Slider Labels","Field Note","Text Validation Type OR Show Slider Number","Text Validation Min","Text Validation Max",Identifier?,"Branching Logic (Show field only if...)","Required Field?","Custom Alignment","Question Number (surveys only)","Matrix Group Name","Matrix Ranking?"
participant_id,participant_information,,text,"Participant ID",,,,,,y,,,,,,
dob,participant_information,,text,"Date of birth",,,date_dmy,,,y,,y,,,,
pi_completeness,participant_information,,dropdown,"Record Completeness","1,1 Complete | 2,2 Incomplete - followup (specify) | 3,3 Incomplete - no followup (specify) | 4,4 Declined (specify) | 5,5 No data - missed window | 6,6 No data - child (specify) | 7,7 No data - parent (specify) | 8,8 No data - equipment (specify) | 9,9 No data - experimenter (specify) | 10,10 No data - other (specify) | 11,11 NA - pilot | 12,12 NA - other (specify)",,,,,,,,,,,
```

To create user interface I prefer Django and its convinient ORM.

At the moment I faced with problem of generating Django models from DataFrame, which I already can optain.
Are there any ways exist to do it easily? I dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask